# Spinor Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors

Why should the transformation between the solutions of the Dirac equation for different inertial observers be linear?

Comment: I don't get the down-votes. This is not a trivial or stupid question, although the answer is probably in between something like "because it works" and "because we want the solutions of the equation to be a (linear) representation of the Lorentz group". It is still worthwhile to explain why non-linear representations of the Lorentz group would not work (which I would guess, is due to the linear structure of quantum theories, if you work out the details) and point to Wigner's classification as the result of the representation theory of the Poincaré group.